# Magento 1.7 - Ebay/Amazon M2E Pro ver 6.0.8 - Cron job is not working

Tags: magento-1.7

We are using **M2E Pro ver 6.0.8** extension in our live website. Cron job is running partially in the current version of M2E Pro 6.0.8. We have run the log files for checking the cron and it works partially.

Could you please see the screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

step 1. update to 6.1.6
step 2. if step 1 does not help , - > send email to support!!!

M2E Pro is neither DIY nor open source. Why posting your questions here if you have support teams looking after you???